# Struggling with Python and Selenium, need help Figuring out how to recognize and clck on an element in an unordered list

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

First week trying to learn Python and Selenium, and am struggling. I am looking at an Unordered list, and I know that I want to make "active" the element with the information of "<li tabindex="0" class="col tablink js-class-weekday" data-index="3" data-day="day-number-4" included in it.

This is the entire HTML of the unordered list:

`<ul class="row c-schedule-calendar__unordered-list-toggle js-unordered-list-toggle" id="js-class-schedule-weekdays-container">`

```
        </li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="col tablink js-class-weekday" data-index="1" data-day="day-number-2">Sat, Mar 20
        </li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="col tablink js-class-weekday" data-index="2" data-day="day-number-3">Sun, Mar 21
        </li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="col tablink js-class-weekday" data-index="3" data-day="day-number-4">Mon, Mar 22
        </li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="col tablink js-class-weekday" data-index="4" data-day="day-number-5">Tue, Mar 23
        </li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="col tablink js-class-weekday" data-index="5" data-day="day-number-6">Wed, Mar 24
        </li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="col tablink js-class-weekday" data-index="6" data-day="day-number-7">Thu, Mar 25
        </li>
</ul>
```

How do I search for that particular bit of element, and then "click" on it? When I search on the element in the code below, and print it, there is no reference to any of the elements in the list.

My relevant Python Code so far is:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

#Using Firefox to access the Web
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
#profile.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()

#Find the unordered list that contains the 4th day and then click on the element that is the 4th day
Seven_Days = driver.find_element_by_class_name('c-schedule-calendar__unordered-list-toggle')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a guessing game without having access to the actual webpage but maybe try one of these...

```
Seven_Days = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul/li[3]")

Seven_Days = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul/li[@data-index='3']")

Seven_Days = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='js-class-schedule-weekdays-container']/li[3]")
```

The first 2 are assuming there are no other lists on the page

Comment: Thanks so much. I used the 2nd suggestion you provided, and it worked perfectly. I added the .click() function to the end of the line and I was able to select it. Now on to the next hurdle. I must work on my understanding the syntax of these find_element options.

Comment: No problem.  Please mark the answer as accepted if you can.  As far as the find elements go, once you get the hang of reading the HTML hierarchy it becomes much, much simpler. I still struggle with the complicated cases, but through lots of practice I got much better.  Its not that difficult once you get the hang of it

Comment: Answer marked as accepted. I am trying to skin this cat two ways, with WebDriver and Requests. I think both have their pros and cons. Once again, thanks very much.